# UNKNOWN CIPHER - NEED HELP DETERMINING (SOLVING)

Tags: cipher, number-sequence

I am trying to figure out how to decrypt and also re-encrypt potentially the following, meaning that i could write a random text string and it would generate that encryption and also decrypting it produces the same text string.

> Railusa.100 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110F5793D
>
> Railusa.200 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110F6793D
>
> Railusa.300 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110F7793D
>
> Railusa.400 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110F0793D
>
> Railusa.500 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110F1793D
>
> Railusa.600 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110F2793D
>
> Railusa.700 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110F3793D
>
> Railusa.800 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110FC793D
>
> Railusa.900 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110FD793D
>
> Railusa.910 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110FD783D
>
> Railusa.920 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110FD7B3D
>
> Railusa.930 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110FD7A3D
>
> Railusa.940 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110FD7D3D
>
> Railusa.950 = PW_2AE07A4495B46110FD7C3D

Any help in determining the type of encryption used will help me tremendously.

You are my last resort in helping me figure out what this is.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it is a cipher? What is its source?

Comment: @WeatherVane I believe it is a XOR Cipher, i just dont know how to confirm it. Also my grammer may be off since i speak 3 languages, i ask for forgiveness there.

Comment: Is there a typo in the 4th one (Railusa.500)? Should `C3` be `93` as in the others?

Comment: @DeerSpotter due to the shortness of the sample text, I am not optimistic about this being solvable.

Comment: @Brandon_J i will add more strings for us to see, i would really like to solve this...

Comment: Wait you are using a tool?  What tool are you using?

Comment: @Brandon_J i updated the strings above, the 37 was completely random. That is gone now. Also, in the past i have given names to such tools and the community backlash was too great because everyone then formed a opinion too quickly. i just want to focus on the cipher please.

Comment: Yes, but the tool will make it easier to determine the process.

Comment: @WeatherVane ty for that catch, it turns out that one computer generated a random string yet 2 others generated with 93. Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned in an answer it is impossible to find the pattern of `XOR` values. The inputs only differ by one or two characters, in the same positions, as do their ciphers.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this is

> An XOR Cipher with a key (at least the first 11 characters) of
>  78 81 13 28 E0 C7 00 3E C4 49 0D

What points to this is as a possibility is

> If you assume two hex characters per character, then the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 correspond to F6, F7, F0, F1, F2.  XOR-ing the values together gives C4.

With the new information

> The XOR with the key given below is consistent

But

> There is no way to confirm with the information given.  However, if it is an XOR Cipher, then the key (at least the first 11 characters) are 78 81 13 28 E0 C7 00 3E C4 49 0D.  This key is XOR'd with the ASCII values of the original text and a "PW_" is pre-pended.

Comment: i will generate a little bit more of these strings, i am trying to figure out how my tool creates these ciphers so i could recreate them manually. The 37 could potentially just follow a pattern as something unique this software uses, this is why i think i need at least 10-15 strings so we could see it.

Comment: So it turns out the 37 was completely random, i tried a different PC to generate the strings the same way and the 37 dissapeared. I updated the above OP to include more data.